# Spring Actuator Running inside EKS and AWS cloudwatch

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

I have enabled actuator end points in my springboot microservice which is deployed inside AWS EKS pod. Now i want to push health information to AWS cloudwatch. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution yet?

Comment: yeah, I have achieved via open-telemetry.- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-open-telemetry.html